# How do I query datastore entities that have any value for a certain property efficiently?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have the following model

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
```

I can query all the User entities that have no name by doing the following:

```
users_without_names = User.query(User.name == None).fetch(100)
```

But how do I query User entities with names, without using != None?

I also need to add another inequality filter on another property, and using != will translate into an equality filter, so I'd like to avoid !=.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Note in [!= and IN Operations](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#neq_and_in) documentation warns that Entities without a property are not indexed.  It is more efficient to choose a [sentinel value](http://elearning.algonquincollege.com/coursemat/pincka/dat2219d.f03/lectures/16-SentinelRepetitions.htm) such as "_no_name_" that will be indexed, and search for that.  Of course your remaining code must process sentinel values as blank where appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

You could search for all names > ""

```
users_with_names = User.query(User.name > "").fetch(100)
```

Comment: As I asked, is there a way without using an inequality filter?